# Why isn't Vue rendering this space? A bug?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two vue properties `firstName` and `lastName`.   Let's say the value of these properties are Tim and Smith.  When I display them as a complete name, I display these properties and include a space between them if they both contain values.  However, Vue omits the space in the output and displays TimSmith.  But if I change to code to output a comma space if both properties have values then it properly ouputs Tim, Smith.  Feels like a bug.  Can anyone explain how to achieve my goal with Vue of only including a space between the two properties if they both contain values and explain why I'm seeing what I am?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="appTemplate">
            {{firstName}}<template v-if="firstName!='' && lastName!=''"> </template>{{lastName}}<br />
            {{firstName}}<span v-if="firstName!='' && lastName!=''"> </span>{{lastName}}<br />
            {{firstName}}<template v-if="firstName!='' && lastName!=''">, </template>{{lastName}}<br />
            {{firstName}} {{lastName}}<br />
        </div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#appTemplate',
                data: {
                    firstName: "Tim",
                    lastName: "Smith"
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The above code produces the output below. Why isn't there a space between Tim and Smith in the first two lines?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `&nbsp;` symbol as space.

Also as a one of ways to get the same result

```
{{(firstName + ' ' + lastName).trim()}}
```

Comment: &nbsp; unfortunately isn't quite the same as a space since it won't allow the name to wrap if the room for it is constrained.  With regard to your 2nd suggestion, I need to include the space only if both firstName and lastName are not blank.  Does the code I present appear to illustrate a Vue bug to you?

Comment: @RonC so second way is a good for you. read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: >Does the code I present appear to illustrate a Vue bug to you?
Nope. This is default behavior of browser.

Comment: thanks for helping with this. Your second way does work.   And Wow, you are right `Tim<span> </span>Smith<br />` (space between the span tags), even when I type it into the HTML directly, does omit the space when output and outputs TimSmith to the browser.  I'm surprised to say the least.  I understand that multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space, but why is the single space in the span omitted all together? Can you explain why this is the behavior or point me to a reference?

Comment: @RonC this article has some good info https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33

Comment: That helps.  Always learning new things about html even after 20+ years of coding html.